# Get patches-own values

Tags: netlogo

how can I get the value of a given netlogo patches-own. I can only get the patches-own names (with .word.program.patchesOwn()) but I don't know how to get their values.

thanks

Comment: are you using the Extensions API, or the Controlling API?

Comment: I don't know. What I do is:
HeadlessWorkspace workspace = HeadlessWorkspace.newInstance();
And then I got the patchesOwn() with:
workspace.world().program().patchesOwn()

Comment: Ah, you're using the controlling API (https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Controlling-API).

Comment: OK, but I do not see in there a way to get the own patches values. I just read this concerning the patches: `workspace.report(
"count patches with [pcolor = green]"))`. Do I need to pass a string to the report function to get a patch value ? For instance, what should I do to get the FOOD patch value in the Ants.nlogo from the Models Library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the values from all of the patches, or the value from a particular patch, or what?

I'll suppose you want the value from a particular patch.

Assuming, to begin with:

```
import org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace;

HeadlessWorkspace workspace = HeadlessWorkspace.newInstance();
workspace.open("models/Sample Models/Biology/Ants.nlogo");
workspace.command("setup");
```

Then you don't need anything other than `HeadlessWorkspace.report` to retrieve a value from a patch, so e.g.:

```
double food = ((Double) workspace.report("[food] of patch -17 -19")).doubleValue();
```

Another, more cumbersome solution path involves accessing engine data structures directly:

```
Patch p = workspace.world().getPatchAt(-17, -19);    
int foodIndex = workspace.world().program().patchesOwn().indexOf("FOOD");
double food = ((Double) p.getPatchVariable(foodIndex)).doubleValue();
```

Comment: Thanks ! Actually I would like to parse all the calls to patch statements in a given nlogo script. For instance, for ants, I'd like to get: ```Seq("sum [food] of patches with [pcolor = cyan]", "sum [food] of patches with [pcolor = sky]", "sum [food] of patches with [pcolor = blue]")```. The idea is to make a wizard in [OpenMOLE](http://openmole.org), which builds automatically an OpenMOLE script set with relevant inputs and outputs; so that it is ready to run through OpenMOLE.

Comment: Any idea ? Is it necessary to do a home made parsing ? Or is there some stuff available to get this parsing through the Netlogo API or through the Netlogo parsing tools ? Thanks

Comment: Please open a new question.